# Library that can generate both PDF and Excel

Tags: c#, reporting

I'm looking for a library that can generate ***both*** PDF and Excel files (which will be returned on-the-fly by a web service).

It's going to be used for reporting.

(please don't suggest that I should use OLE automation since it's pretty worthless in a server environment)

Comment: Is a commercial library an option ?

Comment: Sorry, but I think You'll have to use at least two separate libraries.

Comment: Do you want create any sort of PDF or "just a PDF from the Excel file" ?

Comment: @Yahia: I want to generate "real" PDF files.

Comment: please see my answer below... I use different libraries for "real PDF" and Excel since "real PDF" needs a higher level of control over the creation process than Excel libraries (which are capable of creating PDF) offer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Options to create Excel files:**

MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

*The commercial libraries all can create Excel and also a PDF from an Excel file...*

**Options to create PDF files:**

IF you want to create any PDF then there are also several free and commercial options like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx), [Gnostice PDF.One](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_dot_Net.asp) etc.

Comment: Which one have you used and prefer? And why?

Comment: @jgauffin I used several: Aspose.Cells allows for extremely well and deep support of all things Excel (old and new versions etc.), Flexcel is very nice if you want to create reports based on pre-existing Excel files (which can used as tamplates) - both create nice PDFs too.

Comment: @jgauffin I haven't used SpreadsheetGear but it seems extremely capable and fast (and MS chose it for some product).

Comment: @jgauffin For PDFs I mostly use Gnositce PDF.One since it allows for advanced features including PDF Forms etc. and is easy to use. Aspose.PDF integrates very well with other Aspose-Libraries and can for example extract text content from existing PDFs.

Comment: @jgauffin the vendor support of Gnostice, TMS Software and Aspose is really fine in my experience...

Comment: I chosed TSM Software / Flexcel.